# Balls in Urn, die, few beginner probability questions

Tags: probability

Hello there could anyone help to tell me what they think of what I have tried for the following[image]

For the question about the urn , a)

I used the law of total probability and multiplied $\frac{1}{3}$ by the sum of the probability that a ball was blue in each individual urn. I got $0.2777$ and for b) $0.527$ by using Bayes theorem.

for die I am not so sure, if it were just X being one roll, I would get $E(X)=4.25$ and $V(X)= 2.6875$, but having X be the maximum of two rolls, I am not as sure. Any comments about that?

For for the box one I calculated $P=0.3359$ I did this by considering the sum of each possible ways in which this could occur. ie GRRR, RGRR, RRGR, RRRR

So, out of the questions I put answers to, are they all wrong or are any correct? and also, if in the die question we consider X as I wrote, then is it correct? further, any hint for how to deal with what the question actually asks about ( max of two roll).

Comment: This question is a mess! Either you post each section as a separate question, or make some effort and write them down properly instead of pasting an image from your homework.

Comment: Also, it would help if you tell us how did you arrive to such numbers What was your  thought process?

Comment: For the die, since it is a maximum with two rolls, just write the 36 possibilities, their maximum and probability.  It will be easier to calculate E(X) and Var(X)

Comment: Asking one to check numerical answers given to several decimal places is usually unreasonable. What an experienced person can do quickly is to check the *logical structure* of an argument/calculation.

Comment: @barakmanos  First of all, it is not homework. It is from an exam in 2010. Second of all, a common question asked on this site is what the point of questions in books that don't come with solutions, and answers are commonly "you can post here and people can check"  So that is all this is. I am not asking for you to do the question. In fact I think it is extremely obvious what is written and not a mess. I wrote what my answers were to the questions in the picture.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I understand this. But how else is one supposed to check answers to questions? I could provide all my work, but it will almost surely be very similar to whatever the approach may be , say, involving the formulas used etc

Comment: Unless something numerically odd happens, I think that checking whether $(29.7) (114.43)$ is whatever it is does not really suit this site.

Comment: @PersonaA: You should provide all your work.

Answer (score 0):

You should keep your probabilities as fractions and not as decimals, to avoid round-off error.  Your answers of $0.277$ and $0.527$ are close to

$$
P(\text{blue}) = \frac{1}{3} \left( \frac{2}{9}+\frac{1}{6}+\frac{4}{9} \right)
               = \frac{5}{18}
$$

and

\begin{align}
P(\text{urn 3} \mid \text{blue})
    & = \frac{P(\text{urn 3, blue})}{P(\text{blue})} \\
    & = \frac{\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)\left(\frac{4}{9}\right)}{\frac{5}{18}} \\
    & = \frac{8}{15}
\end{align}

For the die problem, let $Y$ and $Z$ be the two die rolls, and write out expressions for $X$ in terms of $Y$ and $Z$.  For instance,

$$
P(X = 1) = P(Y = 1, Z = 1)
$$
$$
P(X = 2) = P(Y = 1, Z = 2)+P(Y = 2, Z \leq 2)
$$

and so on.  Evaluate the expressions based on the die probability distribution, and then calculate $E(X)$ and $Var(X)$ as usual.

For the marble problem, your approach is mostly valid, except that RRRR is not a satisfactory sequence.